# Usage of stack and Queue?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I am reading datastructures and see stack and queue but i do not get enough examples in computer systems or web development or specific problems where i should use a stack or queue or a tree etc.

Comment: Was your assignment to give examples of the use of stack, queues or trees, perhaps?

Comment: there isnt a assignment i am just curious. Moreover i am not a college going student.

Comment: ha ha -1 for being curious. Anways atleast i have some answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stacks are used by most (all?) programming languages to keep track of the state of the program when sub-routines are called.

**Explanation**: The code of your program is stored in main memory. The CPU has an instruction pointer that always points to the next instruction that will be executed. When an instruction has been executed, this pointer is increased by one, to point to the next instruction.

When your program enters a sub-routine, the instruction pointer jumps to some other address. When that routine is finished, it has to know where it left of. So, the last address before the jump is pushed on the stack. When the function is finished, the topmost item on the stack will be that address.

This is also the reason why excessive recursion can lead to a stack-overflow. Too many nested calls lead to many return addresses being pushed on the stack, but none are removed.

Read more on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Trees can be used for many things, for instance [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Comment: Can u please describe "keep track of the state of the program when sub-routines are called"

Comment: @sushil: added an explanation and a link for call-stacks.

Answer (score 3):

Queues are common whereever something needs to be handled on a first-come-first-serve principle. Network packets, I/O requests, etc.

You want a stack when you need to re-use the last item you put on it again. I can't find a nice example off the top of my hat, but it's used e.g. in converting normal mathematical expressions into RPN or for storing nodes when doing a depth-first search in a graph.

Answer (score 2):

Queue - First In First Out, used for sequntial processing of data. Can be used for processing tasks in the order they were enqueued.
Stack is the opposite of the Queue - Last In First Out, most commonly used example - method call stack.

Comment: can you please elaborate method call stack?

Comment: @sushil - How about a simpler example of LIFO? Think of the undo feature in your word processor. You need to store each thing you did so you can undo it later, and when you access it you want to start from the last item (top of the stack) and work backwards to the first item.

Comment: @JohnFx - there are times when i feel i should have ability to keep clicking upvotes. Ur answer is one among them

Answer (score 1):

In stack deletion and insertion are performed on the same end. So it is called Last In First Out. In stack only one pointer is used called TOP.No wastage of memory space

In queue deletion and insertion are performed on two ends. So, it is called First In First Out. In queue two pointer called as FRONT and REAR.Wastage of memory space.